# gridfs How to read chunk in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

```
fs = gridfs.GridFS(client[db_name])
fs.find_one(file_id).readchunk()
```

How can I read all the chunks of a gridout? When I use readchunk function in a for-loop, it just keep on returning me the first chunk of the gridout.

The api document of gridfs: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/gridfs/grid_file.html#gridfs.grid_file.GridOut

Answer (score 0):

Chunks are internal to the GridFS implementation. You should be using `read` or `readline`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I used `read()`, the program would soon shut down probably because of running out of memory. FYI: my file is around 64mb large. For `readline()`, can I have some examples of how to use it?

Comment: `grid_out.seek(pos=0);

grid_out.readline();

grid_out.seek(pos=grid_out.tell());

grid_out.readline();`


It works! Thanks